# recoding based on non missing cell value in r

Tags: r, recode

I have a dataset looks like

```
   df1 <- data.frame(Id=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L),pricetag=c(NA,5,NA,3,NA),category=c(NA,"Z",NA,NA,"Y"),stringsAsFactors=F)

> df1
  Id pricetag category
1  1       NA       NA
2  2        5       Z
3  3       NA       NA
4  4        3       NA
5  5       NA       Y
```

for the non-missing pricetag values, I would like to recode the category variable as "X". So I am looking something like this.

```
> df1
  Id pricetag category
1  1       NA       NA
2  2        5       X
3  3       NA       NA
4  4        3       X
5  5       NA       Y
```

I could not figure out an `ifelse()` function with `!is.na()` integration.

Any ideas?

Comment: To me, the way you wrote the code is logically sound, but it transforms every NA value to "X" in the category column. I need to transform those that are not missing.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. What if I have a value already in the category variable. I slightly modifie3d the dataset. Your function overwrites and returns this "Y" value into NA. Is there a tweak to keep "Y" as it is while recoding "X"s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform(df1, category = replace(category, !is.na(pricetag), "X"))
#  Id pricetag category
#1  1       NA     <NA>
#2  2        5        X
#3  3       NA     <NA>
#4  4        3        X
#5  5       NA        Y
```

Comment: One last thing, I apologize. What if, let's say, second "category" value was filled with "Z" already. How can I transform it to "X" as well? The function only transforms NA values to "X". Sorry, I am encountering the issues as I go.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L),pricetag=c(NA,5,NA,3,NA),category=c(NA,"Z",NA,NA,"Y"),stringsAsFactors=F)
> df1
  Id pricetag category
1  1       NA     <NA>
2  2        5        Z
3  3       NA     <NA>
4  4        3     <NA>
5  5       NA        Y
> df1$category[which(!is.na(df1$pricetag))] <- 'X'
> df1
  Id pricetag category
1  1       NA     <NA>
2  2        5        X
3  3       NA     <NA>
4  4        3        X
5  5       NA        Y
```

The `which` call identifies the rows of `df1` which are not NA, and then assigns `X` to those rows' category column regardless of current value. Is this what you needed?